# Delay Turbolink's visit for off-canvas menu to close

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, turbolinks

I'm using TurboLinks and a [off-canvas menu](http://tympanus.net/Development/OffCanvasMenuEffects/) that closes with an animation. By the time, Turbolinks changes the page before the menu is completely closed and it seems a little rushed. I've tried adding a timeouts and tinkering with TurboLinks' events but without any luck. Javascript/Jquery is **really** not my strong suit, so, my question: is there a way to delay the firing of the TurboLinks' request so the menu can close normally?

Pd. I'm developing with Laravel.

### Update:

In the [documentation](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#canceling-visits-before-they-start) I've found that you can't cancel de visit before it starts. With that in mind, I set this

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:before-visit', function(e){
    var url = event.data.url;
    console.log(url);
    event.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    setTimeout(function(url){
        Turbolinks.visit(url);
    }, 1000);
});
```

But, as I said in the comments line with [@OhGodWhy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1206267/ohgodwhy) everything crumbles, the page gets stuck and the error "maximum call stack size exceeded" is shown multiple times in the console.

Answer (score 0):

There is an RFC out there that dictates you cannot slow/stop the process of a user leaving the page without their intervention; hence why you see `alert` windows popping up whenever you want to leave the page, but you can click 'continue' to proceed to leave anyway.

That said, I can give you a solution. All of their animations are CSS3 driven, the only javascript you need to worry about is the one that toggles the class.

```
$('.sidebar').on('click', 'a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    if ($('body').hasClass('st-menu-open')) {
        $('body').removeClass('st-menu-open')
        setTimeout(function(){
           Turbolinks.visit($this.prop('href'));
        }, 500);
    }
});
```

All we're doing here is caputring the click in your nav, if the body has the class, then we're going to remove it. However, we're going to wait `500ms` which corresponds to the `CSS transition delay` that the library uses, until we execute the redirection. This way, after 500 ms, the transition will be completed and you can redirect the user.

Comment: I've tried that (Sorry, I should've mention that), but the problem with this "window.location = $this.prop('href');" is that I'm bypassing or disabling the TurboLinks effects, or well, that's what I suppose bc the page loads like a "normal" page.

Comment: @JorgeAnzola Sorry, I was moving too fast. I knew that already, please review the timeout function again. I think you can call the `.visit()` method off of `TurboLinks` manually.

Comment: I found in the docs that you can't [cancel a visit before ir starts](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#canceling-visits-before-they-start) and I did, they also pointed out that you can get the visit url with event.data.url, so I did `var url = event.data.url;`.

As you certainly mentioned, I can [call visit method ](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#turbolinksvisit). I wrote `Turbolinks.visit(url);` wrapped into a setTimeOut(). But now, when I clic a link, everything goes to hell, I got a ' maximum call stack size exceeded' error and the page gets stuck.

Comment: @JorgeAnzola I'm guessing there's something internal in the click function that `e.preventDefault()` doesn't stop. Can you tell me, does `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` help you?

Comment: Ok, now the page doesn't explode. IDK where that method came from, but it worked (first win!). Now, the visit method doesn't work within the setTimeOut (It does when you call out side). You think I'm passing the url variable wrong? (Check the OP update)

Comment: @JorgeAnzola If you `console.log(url)` (make sure you have your inspector open), do you get a value?

Comment: Yes. It shows me the proper link. But wait, I just noticed something weird. Give a moment and I'll update you.

Comment: It's stuck in a loop! But I don't know why.
console.log shows `http://localhost:8000/about-me` and then immediately  `x http://localhost:8000/`. Where **x** is a number that increments every second. It's like the visit method just doesn't stop making requests.

(I've updated the code block in the OP)